# jscookie.js how to expire cookie in minutes not days?

Tags: jquery, cookies, js-cookie

I'm using this jquery cookie named [jscookie.js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and I've read over the readme and even implemented into my project.

The readme explains how to expire a cookie in 'days', but not hours or minutes.

> Create a cookie that expires 7 days from now, valid across the entire
>   site:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```

How do I set a cookie to expire in minutes or hours?

Comment: The wiki addresses this, which is a pretty common question: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#expire-cookies-in-less-than-a-day

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer in:
[Frequently-Asked-Questions](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)

> JavaScript Cookie supports a Date instance to be passed in the expires
>   attribute. That provides a lot of flexibility since a Date instance
>   can specify any moment in time.
>
> Take for example, when you want the cookie to expire 15 minutes from
>   now:

```
var inFifteenMinutes = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 15 * 60 * 1000);
Cookies.set('foo', 'bar', {
    expires: inFifteenMinutes
});
```

> Also, you can specify fractions to expire in half a day (12 hours):

```
Cookies.set('foo', 'bar', {
    expires: 0.5
});
```

> Or in 30 minutes:

```
Cookies.set('foo', 'bar', {
    expires: 1/48
});
```

Comment: I would suggest at least linking to the anchor, because the Wiki will change and the content might stay out of view.

Answer (score 3):

You can just divide by the minutes in a day.

`Cookies.set('name','value', {expires: (1 / 1440) * minutes });`

Answer (score 1):

Give it an instance of [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object with the date when you want your cookie to expire:

```
// Time in the future
var expire = Date.now();

// Add period in minutes
expire.setMinutes(expire.getMinutes() + 40);

// Add period in hours
expire.setHours(expire.getHours() + 3);

Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: expire});
```